# How to add elevation to the textInputLayout in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I try to add elevation to my TextInputLayout but android:elevation="10dp doesn't work!
How can I do this?

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:elevation="10dp>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: By default, `View`s won't cast a shadow unless they have a non-null background set, and `TextInputLayout` doesn't have one. It manages the background on the nested `EditText` instead. You could simply set your own background on it, but that might taking some fiddling to get it to line up correctly with the other decorations. Also, it's not clear how you want this to look, exactly, but I should mention that the shadow will not be affected by `TextInputLayout`'s cutout, and the floating hint has no background of its own, so you might end up with some ugly artifacts in certain styles/themes.

Comment: I just realized that for the basic style, you might be able to get away with only setting `android:outlineProvider="bounds"` on the `<TextInputLayout>`. That'll cause the shadow to be strictly rectangular, but with a small corner radius it's not really noticeable: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqizJ.png.